# Windows covering all screens - even struts - full screen failing

Tags: xcb

I have created two monitors. I created two windows. I moved them to the different monitors and made them full screen. Now while the window has focus, all the reserved "struts" (i think they are called) are covered. However when the window does not have focus, the "struts" from the back show over the window.

Is there anyway to temporarily make my window top most (even over all struts). I do set my windows to be always on top.

Comment: This depends entirely on the window manager. The only thing you can do is make your windows override_redirect windows, force them to be on top and hope the window manager doesn't fight you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "making your window fullscreen", you mean that you sent a `_NET_WM_STATE` client message for the `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` atom.

As such, this request is handled entirely by the window manager. This includes not only honoring or rejecting the request, but it also means that the window manager gets to decide what "fullscreen" means, i.e., whether or at which point other clients are visible despite the fullscreen (though the specs certainly make it clear how fullscreen should be interpreted).

The bottom line is that your window is still a managed window and while your own window always wants to do its own thing, it's the window manager's responsibility (and, more importantly, its *right*) to weigh the wish of an individual client against everything else.

Long story short: no, there's no way. In fact the request of going fullscreen could be entirely rejected already and that would be fine. *You* have the responsibility to deal with what the window manager decides to do here.

That said – you *can* choose to not have your window redirected, i.e., make it unmanaged. You can do this by making it an `override_redirect` window, but it being unmanaged will also mean no decorations, no window manager interaction whatsoever etc.

Anyhow, raising an unmanaged window doesn't result in a configure request anymore, but will simply be honored by the X server. See `man XRaiseWindow`:

> If the override-redirect attribute of the window is False and some other client has selected SubstructureRedirectMask on the parent, the X server generates a ConfigureRequest event, and no processing is performed.  Otherwise, the window
>          is raised.

Of course the window manager (or other clients) will still be able to notice this and might react by raising some other window in return again (though this is unlikely). Screen lockers such as i3lock have this problem and the only way to solve it is by listening for visibility events yourself and raising the window once again, hoping you and the other window don't run into a never-ending fight.

Generally I'd reconsider whether you really want to do this. If the window manager decides that this is the feel it wants to provide, you shouldn't mess with it. Is it really that crucial that your window is still the only visible window on the output if it doesn't even have focus?

Comment: Ah wow thank you sir so much this is an incredible reply. I have been struggling with this for months - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/issues/27 - In this github issue, do you think this `overide_redirect` method will work. I made a screenshot tool which overlays all monitors with an image of itself, and a editor on top of that. So its expected behavior by user.

Comment: Yes, I think override_redirect may be a valid approach in your case since the overlay isn't supposed to be experienced as a normal, movable, resizable window by the user anyway.

Comment: Thank you sir so much I'm going to go forward with this appraoch and I'll update you on how it goes :) And yep that is how I made it full screen with that method you metnioned.

Comment: Note that making it fullscreen that way will no longer work now since you are bypassing the window manager. You'll need to configure the window to the appropriate size yourself (and position it).

Comment: Ah interesting. If you have a chance later would you be able to show some xcb code to do this. I was thinking of using the equivalent of `XChangeProperty`. I have never used `XRaiseWindow` I have only used  `XSendEvent` to send it a message. As I am new to porting xcb to js-ctypes it would help a lot. But based on your other solution I have a superb guide and can get it done, so if you're too busy no problem at all! =)

Comment: Take a look at the i3lock source code. It creates an override_redirect window covering the entire screen and raises it – all using xcb. It also reacts on visibility events to raise the window again. Just search its code for "raise" to see how to raise windows using xcb.

Comment: Hey @Ingo I was studying the code here - https://github.com/i3/i3lock/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=raise - I don't understand why the need for re-raise. Isn't it possible to just "set always on top"?

Comment: @Noitidart No, the "always on top" thing is just a protocol that needs to be ensured by the window manager. But your window isn't managed anymore. You need to reraise the window whenever another window obstructs it. Again, this means you *could* end up fighting another application. That's what the protocol is for; to let the window manager coordinate things. But as you've seen in your original question, the window manager may decide against you.

Comment: Ahh I got it now. Will forge ahead! :)

Comment: Hey there @Ingo, the code in i3lock was creating a new window with `xcb_create_window` and they had set the mask to include this `overide_redirect` https://github.com/i3/i3lock/blob/59705b05b5533bcb78d4c92966379914aa7b656d/xcb.c#L113 - is it possible to do to an already created window? Because I let the browser create the window and then I take over. Because I need the window with the html "compiler", so I cant create a fresh window.

Comment: @Noitidart ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/xcb_change_window_attributes.3.xhtml

Comment: However, I think you may have to do this at least before the window is mapped.

Comment: Ah thanks Ingo. I'll try to do map and flush after I set the properties and see if that makes an affect hopefully. Or maybe should I unmap it first then remap it?

Comment: Ideally you want to do it before the window ever gets mapped (if possible) to avoid flickering. I'm not familiar with Firefox plugin development, so I'm not sure what it can or cannot do, sorry. I also didn't quite understand why you need to have Firefox create the window, either.

Comment: Ah thanks Ingo. I'll experiement with it and report back. The reason I need Firefox to make the window though is because my addon is html. I get the screenshot data with native calls and feed transfer the array buffer to my addon. So now the only way I can make a cross platform solution is with javascript and the html5 api. Windows created with firefox support loading html files. My "app" basically extends firefox to create a window on each monitor, then on each I put a screenshot of that monitor, and then users use  the editor to edit/crop then upload to image server or disk etc.

Comment: Please try it out if you have some time :) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - this is the released version, not using xcb for the window stuff so its got that funky window behavior.

Comment: Hi Ingo I'm having trouble understanding `*_request_t` vs `*_reply_t` interchangeability may you please see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37095392/1828637

Comment: Absolutely absolytely cool! Thank you so much this all worked! I had to actually call `xcb_unmap_window` first then call `xcb_map_window` again after that and then `xcb_flush`. And then I had to use `xcb_set_input_focus` and `xcb_grab_keyboard` to get the keyboard working in the window, I'm not sure about this keyboard focus thing I have to investigate it more. But getting it to open without interference by system stuff was an issue for me for soooo long, thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: This is the code - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/screenshot/ScreenshotWorker.js#L733-L773 - if you can take a peak at it and any comments would be so welcome! :)

Comment: Yes, you need to set the focus yourself because focus is handled by the window manager, but as with other things before: you are now bypassing the window manager, so it won't do that for you anymore. You should definitely query the input focus before your window is opened and restore it afterwards, otherwise you might leave the focus in a rather broken state after your window closes. Look at the code for i3-input (in the i3 repository) for reference.

Comment: Also, you should first unmap, then make it an override_redirect window and then map it again. Making such changes in the withdrawn state is good practice because that's where the window manager won't interfere. If you make the change before unmapping it, the window manager might react in some way.

Comment: Oh interesting. Should I `xcb_unmap_window` then `xcb_flush` then do the changes? Or just unmap then do the changes and have a single flush?

Comment: Only do a single flush. If you flush after unmapping the window, you basically force there to be flickering.

Comment: Oh very interesting thanks! I was thinking the stuff was not taking affect so was flushing after unmap, then after map, then after setting input focus. I'll remove all that and put the flush at the end.

Comment: Hey @Ingo, I have a weird issue. So my window opens as a managed window, after it opens my code executs and does this: `1` unmap `2` xcb_change_window_attributes with XCB_CW_OVERRIDE_REDIRECT to 1 `3` map `4` flush `5` wait 100ms `6` raise with xcb_configure_window `7` resize to full screen width/height with xcb_configure_window `8` xcb_set_input_focus to this window `9` flush ---------------- Does this look right to you? If I don't do the 100ms on OpenSuse the window is open but invisible and no key input takes, its so weird.

Comment: The workflow is OK, but I'd resize it to fullscreen before mapping it. And of course it should work without the delay and only a single flush. I'm not sure why you'd see what you're seeing. Sounds like that'd require some debugging.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for your fast reply, I'll dig into it and let you know if I find anything interesting

Comment: Oh wow, I did a `xcb_get_window_attributes` check after each step. And after `xcb_unmap_window` `map_state` succesfully goes to `XCB_MAP_STATE_UNMAPPED` but SOMETIMES after `xcb_map_window` it is still unmapped, do you think the manager is setting it back to unampped? Is this fight have a familiar solution?

Comment: The window is an override redirect window, so the window manager shouldn't be touching it. Try looking for error events or an error reply if you use the checked XCB call. And perhaps also try running your application under xtrace. Perhaps the mapping request is denied (though it would certainly surprise me if an override redirect window isn't allowed to be mapped).

Comment: I did a while loop of map it until it gets mapped and that fixed it. But I'll try the checked call to see what the error is. and ill try xtrace, thanks so much for your fast replies!