# reply_t vs request_t - passing them in interchangeably?

Tags: xcb

I'm having an issue with XCB. I don't understand the difference between `*_reply_t` vs `*_request_t` types.

It seems that the `*_reply_t` is passed in place of the `*_response_t`, however the structures are very different.

For instance:

```
xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t *reply = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply(
        connection, xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current(connection, root), NULL);
```

So now `reply` is the type of `*_reply_t`. But now I need to use `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs` which expects the first argument to be of type `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_request_t` as per the docs here:

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs.htm

```
          xcb_randr_output_t *xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs(
            const xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_request_t *reply
          );
```

However the response from the first call is of type `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t` (`*_reply_t`). How is it possible to pass this into the outputs call without casting? The structures are completely different per the docs:

```
typedef struct xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t {
    uint8_t         response_type;
    uint8_t         pad0;
    uint16_t        sequence;
    uint32_t        length;
    xcb_timestamp_t timestamp;
    xcb_timestamp_t config_timestamp;
    uint16_t        num_crtcs;
    uint16_t        num_outputs;
    uint16_t        num_modes;
    uint16_t        names_len;
    uint8_t         pad1[8];
} xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t;
```

And the struct for the `*_request_t` is not in the docs I got it from the source code here:

https://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/randr_8h_source.html#l00896

```
   typedef struct xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_request_t {
       uint8_t      major_opcode; 
       uint8_t      minor_opcode; 
       uint16_t     length; 
       xcb_window_t window; 
   } xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_request_t;
```

I do ctypes so I have to declare the type I am going to pass in beforehand for the signature of the method. So I am very confused on how something of a totally different structure (`reply`) is going into a second call which has structure of `request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have stumbled upon is simply a documentation bug. All the functions which claim to take `*_request_t` actually expect `*_reply_t`. From the very source you linked from, just look at the actual function definition (rather than what the man page says) and you'll find

```
xcb_randr_output_t *
    xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs (const xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t *R  );
```

The struct you found is not actually used anywhere in the file, so it's probably some forgotten leftover, or maybe is still kept around for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Ohhh correct! The method signature does not use that in that code file. Doc error for sure. Thanks so much! Fixed up the `response` to `request` in the post :)